# Flask Login Continuously bounces back to log in

Tags: python, post, authentication, flask, get

I can't figure out why I can't get passed the login page.  It doesn't matter if I type in the right or wrong credentials, It reloads the login page, instead of signing me in.

```
import json

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required, login_user, current_user


from bson.objectid import ObjectId

from lib.mongo import db
from scripts.twitter_stats import ratio_of_wiki_links

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = ''
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)


class User(UserMixin):
  def __init__(self, name, password, id, active=True):
    self.name = name
    self.password = password
    self.id = id
    self.active = active

  def is_active(self):
    account = db.accounts.find_one({ "_id": ObjectId("561c7990e4b060b59d7cbcd1")})
    if not account['username'] == self.name and account['password'] == self.password:
      self.active = False
    return self.active

  def is_anonymous(self):
    return False

  def is_authenticated(self):
    return True

  def get_id(self):
    return str(db.accounts.find_one({'username': self.name})['_id'])

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
  user = db.accounts.find_one({'_id': userid})
  return user

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
  account = db.accounts.find_one({ "_id": ObjectId("561c7990e4b060b59d7cbcd1")})
  password = account['password']
  user = account['username']
  error = None
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.form['username']
    passw = request.form['password']
    if username != user or passw != password:
      error = 'Invalid Credentials, please try again'
    else:
      user = User(username, passw, account['_id'])
      login_user(user)
      return redirect(url_for('home'))
  return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/')
@login_required
def home():
  account = db.accounts.find_one({'account': 'twitter'})
  entry = db.tweets.find().sort([['_id', -1]]).limit(1)
  entry = list(entry)[0]['post']
  # if g.user.is_authenticated():
  #     g.user = user.name
  return render_template('index.html', account=account, entry=entry)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call `add_routes` before run app

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    add_routes(app)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I tried that, I'm still receiving the 404 error:
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Oct/2015 08:05:35] "GET /index.html?username=d&password=d HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: index url is `127.0.0.1/index`, not `/index.html`. Login url is `127.0.0.1/ `. Try `127.0.0.1/?username=d&password=d`

Comment: I know what the url is, I don't know why on the POST it's returning that url.  It's suppose to either render the login.html, which it does just fine when the page is loaded, because that's a GET request.  If the credentials are wrong it should render the login.html as it did in the beginning. If the credentials are right it should proceed to index.  The issue is that it is not doing either.  It's not running any of the code when the POST is made.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you struggling with the same issue, my problem was with the load_user method.  I fixed it by changing it to this:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
  user_rec = db.accounts.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(userid)})
  user = User(user_rec['username'], user_rec['password'], user_rec['_id'])
  return user
```